# how many associated products need to be created

Tags: configurable-product

I have products that have 4 configurable attributes:

Colour (~36 possible options)
Headboard (2 possible options)
Mattress (3 possible options)
Drawer (3 possible options)

I am confused, how many associated products need to be created. I have created 324 but they are not getting assigned to configurable product properly.

Comment: Hello @Sumeet, have you checked my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have 4 attributes with different option values, you need to multiply all option values

You need create:

```
36*2*3*3 = 648 Products
```

For all complete combinations.